# how to auto slide toggle without click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the first div to appear and hide and then the next div should show up and again hide for every 5 seconds automatically. Currently this code is in Slide up but how to change it to **toggle** effect

here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dN4SN/

javascript code is here :

```
$(function() {
    $("#slideContainer").css({
        "height" :$("#slideContainer div:first").css("height"
     "overflow" : "hidden"
    });

    function slide() {
        $("#slideContainer div:first").slideUp(800, function() {
          var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().append(this);
            $this.show();
            slide();
        });
    }
    slide();  
});​
```

html is here:

```
<h1>Test of sliding stuff</h1>
<div id="slideContainer">
    <div>Contact No: 555-666-7777</div>
    <div>Email: me@me.com</div>
    <div>Test: whatever</div>
    <div>Add as many extra lines here as you like</div>
</div>
<div>Other page content here.</div>​
```

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Are you having problems with the timing?

Comment: instead of sliding up, i want it to be like a shake(yahoo messenger buzz effect)